# How many line segments have both their end points located at vertices of a given cube?

Tags: combinatorics

How many line segments have both their end points located at vertices of a given cube? 
**My try:-**
A cube has 8 vertices. Number of line segments = 8C2=28.
(As a line segments has 2 end points)

Comment: This is correct. You can check your answer by counting the edges and the two kinds of diagonals separately and adding the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work! The only thing I'd adjust is this: (1) Each line segment uniquely determines a pair of endpoints. (2) Each pair of endpoints uniquely determines a line segment. The first observation guarantees that you haven't "forgotten" any segments in your counting. The second guarantees that you haven't counted any of the segments more than once. Thus, you're done!